# How to change the name of uploaded file in my custom Entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom Content Entity created with

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type)
```

In the definition, there is a 'file' field:

```
$fields['file1'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
->setLabel(t('Fichier source'))
->setDescription(t('Source document (can be edited)'))
->setSettings([
'target_type' => 'file',
'file_extensions' => 'doc docx odt pages',
'file_directory' => 'contrats',
])
->setDefaultValue('')
->setDisplayOptions('view', [
'label' => 'above',
'type' => 'string',
'weight' => 7,
])
->setDisplayOptions('form', [
'type' => 'string_textfield',
'weight' => 7,
])
->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
->setReadOnly(TRUE);
```

And it works fine!
My question is: how can I change the name of an uploaded file?
I guess I should use hook_entity_presave.
But how to retrieve file information in hook_entity_presave?
Using the comments already given (thanks), I added this:

```
function tempo_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity)
{
if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == "amap_contrats") {
$sName  = 'Contrat-'.$entity->typecontrat->target_id.'-'.str_replace("-", "", $entity->datedebutcontrat->value);
$fid1[0]['target_id'];
$fid1 = $entity->get('file1')->target_id;
$file = file_load($fid1);
$sName1 = $sName.'.'.pathinfo($file->filename->value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$result = file_move($file1, $sName1, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$sName2 = $sName . '.pdf';
$result =file_move($file2, $sName2, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
}
```

And now, I get this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to file_move() must implement interface Drupal\file\FileInterface, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/JdP8M3/modules/custom/tempo/tempo.module on line 48 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/JdP8M3/core/modules/file/file.module on line 216 #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/JdP8M3/modules/custom/tempo/tempo.module(48): file_move(NULL, 'Contrat-5-20170...', 1)
```

Any idea?

OK, I got it! My mistake:
I `load '$file'` and I try to `file_move '$file1'` :-(

Comment: As you said, maybe you can try to use hook_entity_presave, get back file or files uploaded to your content entity, and then process them to rename the file using the file_move() function

Comment: Agreed (I did that in the Drupal 6 version of my site).
My question is more about how to "get back file or files uploaded to the content entity"...

Comment: Can you try on your hook_entity_presave : $files  = $entity->get('file_field_name');
I'm using this on my hook_node_presave, I guess it's the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below articles it will be helpful for you..

[How do I change the uploaded file name after the node has been saved?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/how-do-i-change-the-uploaded-file-name-after-the-node-has-been-saved)

[Changing file name on upload](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110990/changing-file-name-on-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Being newbie in drupal and spending my three hours to alter the form from function `MY_THEME_form_user_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`, I was able to achieve what I wanted. I found `setFileUri` and `file_move` helpful altogether. I am just curious about if there is any loophole if I just use this much code. Do I need to do anything else apart form this?

```
  $file_name = "";
  $username = "";
  $fid_0 = 'photo';
  $uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');

  if ($form_state->hasValue('user_picture')) {
    $username = $form_state->getValue('field_username')[0]['value'];

    $fid_0 = $form_state->getValue('user_picture')[0]['fids'][0];
    $file_name = $uid . '-' . strtolower($username) .'-'. $fid_0;
    $file_name = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z]/", '-', $file_name));
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid_0);

    $old_file_name = $file->getFilename();
    $old_file_name = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file->getFilename());

    $new_filename_uri = str_replace($old_file_name, $file_name, $file->getFileUri());

    file_move($file, $new_filename_uri);
    $file->setFilename($file_name);
    $file->setFileUri($new_filename_uri);
    $file->save();
  }
```